# electronJS: Navigator properties userAgentData.brands incorrect order

Tags: electron

**Actual behaviour**

Navigate too [google](https://www.google.com)

In the developer console execute the following:

`navigator.userAgentData.brands`

Displays Not:A-Brand first

```
[
    {
        "brand": "Not:A-Brand",
        "version": "99"
    },
    {
        "brand": "Chromium",
        "version": "112"
    }
]
```

This order should be reversed, anybody know how to reverse the order?

The expected order should be something like:

```
[
    {
        "brand": "Chromium",
        "version": "112"
    },
    {
        "brand": "Google Chrome",
        "version": "112"
    },
    {
        "brand": "Not:A-Brand",
        "version": "99"
    }
]
```

I've tried different user agent strings, and looked at how to override this value with the preload script (however I suspect it's not possible).